# Window's handle in JAVA

Tags: java, windows, desktop

I am working on a desktop application in java and I want the handle of another window created in some other language running in window in some process. I know it's title, name, image name and other details. I am unable to find an API for this purpose.

Please let me know, is there some API or library to achieve this. We can perform this action in C++ easily like:

```
hwnd = FindWindow(NULL,(LPCWSTR)"XYZ");
```

Comment: The only way to do this in Java is to use native C/C++ code like the method you've mentioned.

Comment: Is there some java API to achieve this similar thing.

Comment: Not that I know of; you'll most likely have to roll your own native implementation. Refer to Adam's answer for JNI, which is Java's native connection functionality.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The easiest solution is [JNA](https://github.com/twall/jna). FindWindow example:

```
WinDef.HWND hWnd = User32.INSTANCE.FindWindow("className", "windowName");
```

Answer (score 1):

Use JNI to get that information. Basically,  JNI lets you create a C++ dll that implements the function and you return the value to the Java application. If you want to use that in an applet though, you will have to sign the applet (can't use dlls otherwise).

Check this out: http://www3.ntu.edu.sg/home/ehchua/programming/java/JavaNativeInterface.html

Comment: JNI will technically do it, but should be the last resort.  Always prefer JNA to JNI...